# No tap menu in Drive

Tags: google-drive

I am trying to switch accounts in My Drive.

My understanding is that this can be done by tapping on the menu in the top LH corner of the screen, as you would do in the Gmail app etc

However on my phone (Samsung Duos) nothing happens - no menu at all.

I have tried completely uninstalling, then restarting and reinstalling. Same result. Also tried clearing the cache/settings in App manager. No luck there either.

Does anyone have any other ideas I could try? I use Drive heaps for my business and personal use (separate accounts) so it's driving me nuts not being able to switch between them!

Comment: SORTED: Not allowed to answer my own question so here is the solution...

Deleted both accounts and recreated them, now it works :)

Comment: As soon as the timeout is gone, you can answer your own question and mark it as accepted to show this problem as resolved for future reference for others :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK got it sorted... just writing this down incase anyone stumbles across the same issue...

Deleted both accounts and recreated them, now it works :)